# integrate the following integral $\int \sqrt{\frac}{a-2y^2}{3} dy$

Tags: calculus

How do I integrate the following.I tried by substituting y=sin t but I did not get anything proper. 
$\int \sqrt{\frac}{a-2y^2}{3} dy$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

You may write the integral as
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{\frac{a-2y^2}{3}}dy&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\int\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}-y^2}dy
\end{align}
Now, using $y=\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\sin t$ we transform the integral into
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{a}{2}\int\cos^2 t\,dt
\end{align}

Comment: Dont we have it as not a square when outside the square root
$\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{a}{2}\int\cos tdt$  @AngelMarioGallegos

Comment: Observe that
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\sin t\qquad\implies\qquad dy=\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\cos t\,dt$$
Then
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\int\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}-y^2}dy=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\int\sqrt{   \frac a2-\frac{a}{2}\sin^2 t}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\cos t\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac a2\int\cos^2 t\,dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Another try. Assuming all variables are positive:

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{a-2y^2}{3}}\space\text{d}y=\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\left(a-2y^2\right)}\space\text{d}y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int\sqrt{a-2y^2}\space\text{d}y=$$

---

substitute $y=\frac{\sqrt{a}\sin(u)}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\text{d}y=\frac{\sqrt{a}\cos(u)}{\sqrt{2}}\space\text{d}u$.

Then $\sqrt{a-2y^2}=\sqrt{a-a\sin^2(u)}=\sqrt{a}\cos(u)$ and $u=\arcsin\left(\frac{y\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)$:

---

$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{6}}\int\sqrt{a}\cos^2(u)\space\text{d}u=\frac{a}{\sqrt{6}}\int\cos^2(u)\space\text{d}u=\frac{a}{\sqrt{6}}\int\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos(2u)}{2}\right]\space\text{d}u$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to transform whats under the the square root into $1-(\text{something})^2$.
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\int \sqrt{\frac{a-2y^2}{3}}dy &=& \int \sqrt{\frac{a}{a}\cdot\frac{a-2y^2}{3}}dy\\
&=& \int \sqrt{\frac{a}{3}\cdot\frac{a-2y^2}{a}}dy\\
&=& \int \sqrt{\frac{a}{3}\cdot\frac{a-2y^2}{a}}dy\\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\int \sqrt{1-\frac{2y^2}{a}}dy\\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\int \sqrt{1-(\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}y)^2}dy\\
&=& \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}}\int \sqrt{1-(\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}y)^2}\cdot \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}dy\\
\end{array}$$
Now substitute, $u=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}y\implies du = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}dy$
$$\color{red}{\frac{a}{\sqrt{6}}}\int\sqrt{1-u^2}du$$
Now try making the substitution $u=\sin v$.

I think you can yake it from here.